# Dynamically add service to $injector

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-injector

I'm trying to dynamically create a service in another service and add it to the inejctor, so that other controllers and services throughout the app can inject it later.  I'm not sure if what I'm even trying to do is possible but I've boiled down what I'm trying to do into an example on [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/zdMsyDW7205zYs9Q4Yms?p=preview)

I'm basically having two modules use each other.  One defines how a service should be configured on the fly, and the other module configures the services on the fly.  I'm not sure what to do while configuring the new dynamic service though so that it can be found by the injector later and used in other controllers,services etc.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically I needed to make a provider instead of a service.  The provider can create factories, values, constants, etc.  See a revised plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsJluU9zkU7vhFywRyIf?p=preview)